# How is SIGAR API calculating the cpu utilization percentage?

Tags: java, cpu-usage, sigar

I am using the below mentioned API to get the CPU utilization percentage. It is giving me the correct value. I just want to know how it internally works.

```
CpuPerc cpuperc = sigar.gerCpuPerc();
```

Comment: The calculations are implemented natively, you can take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/master/src/sigar_format.c#L652)

Comment: Thanks @JulianDurchholz.